# What is this limit equal to? $\lim\limits_{D\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1{D^{\,2}}\right)^D$

Tags: calculus, limits

> What is this limit equal to? $$\lim\limits_{D\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1{D^{\,2}}\right)^D$$

Does this limit exist? I think that it goes to $1$ because: $$\left(1+\dfrac1\infty\right)^\infty=1^\infty=1$$

Thank you.

Comment: $1^\infty$ is an [indeterminate form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form).

Comment: Many thanks!!!!

Comment: You're welcome. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For large values of D, the corresponding Taylor series is

$1 + 1/D + 1/(2 D^2)$

More generally, for $n > 1$, the Taylor expansion of $[1+1/D^n]^D$ starts as $1 + 1 / D^{n-1}$, except for the case of $n=1$ as pointed out by Lab.

Comment: @user40615. Thanks for editing for me. Happy New Year !!

Answer (score 5):

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1{x^2}\right)^x=\left(\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1{x^2}\right)^{x^2}\right)^{\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac1x}=e^0$$

as $\displaystyle \lim_{y\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1y\right)^y=e$

Comment: Many thanks!! I understand now!!

Comment: @Goojk, my pleasure

Comment: Can anyone tell me what is the reasoning behind lab bhattacharjee's solution? I mean the $\lim_x f(x)^{g(x)} = \lim_x f(x)^{\lim_x g(x)}$. Is there some theory to verify this?

Answer (score 3):

For any $x\gt0$, we have $1\leqslant\left(1+\frac1{D^2}\right)^D \lt \left(1+\frac xD\right)^D$ 
when $D$ is sufficiently large. Since $\lim\limits_{D\to\infty}\left(1+\frac xD\right)^D=e^x$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to0^+}e^x=1$, by squeezing principle, $\lim\limits_{D\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1{D^{\,2}}\right)^D=1$.

Answer (score 2):

No. 
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)^x=1.$$

HINT :

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\frac 1x\right)^x=e.$$

Comment: @Goojk: You can see lab bhattacharjee's technique. I strongly suggest you to do it yourself again. This is an important technique.

Answer (score 1):

This is an alternative to Lab's method which may be useful in other problems with exponents.

Take logarithms

$$
\ln \left( 1 + \frac{1}{D^2}\right)^D = D \ln \left( 1 + \frac{1}{D^2}\right) \rightarrow D \cdot \frac{1}{D^2} \rightarrow 0$$

So your limit is $e^0=1$.

Comment: I agree... Study Lab's method. It will improve your skills and get you to approach problems with confidence.